# How to correlate PCI card bus/function or VENDEV and the /dev/ttySn installed from Linux C/C++

Tags: c++, c, linux, serial-port

I am writing a test program to verify serial port operation on any our extensive line of PCI, PCI Express, M.2 (and related busses) single- and multi-port cards.

How can I determine which /dev/ttyS{n} are created by which PCI card, programmatically (CPP), on Linux.

For example, 8-port RS232 Card is installed in a Linux PC, Linux kernel drivers install 8 /dev/ttyS devices successfully, user runs my program, my program must send/receive serial data at several baud rates through each of the 8 ports.

Which 8 ports are from the Unit Under Test ("UUT")?

Well, one Linux box has /dev/ttyS0 through /dev/ttyS31, and /dev/ttyS0 through /dev/ttyS3 are from the motherboard. On this system the UUT's 8 ports get installed as /dev/ttyS4 through /dev/ttyS11 -- but it can/will be different ttyS numbers on different systems/linux images.

I can `lspci -n |grep $VEND:` to find the card ("04:00.0 0700: VEND:DEVI"), take the first 7 bytes (04:00.0) manually and `dmesg | grep 04:00.0 | grep ttyS` to get the list of ports for that card ... but I want to do this from inside a "CPP" program.

I can

```
for (const auto & entry : fs::directory_iterator("/dev/"))
    if (entry.path().filename().string().compare(0,4, "ttyS") == 0 )
        list.push_back( entry.path() );
```

to get a list of all 32 /dev/ttyS devices on this system, but can't tell which are from the UUT.

Worse, some cards are 1, 2, 4, or 8 port.
Worse, multiple multiport cards could be installed simultaneously.

So: How can I determine the VENDEV by which any given /dev/ttyS was created, programmatically? (C/CPP; gcc C++17)

Something involving libpci? (`#include <pci/pci.h>`)

```
`root@systemname:/proc/tty/driver# cat serial
serinfo:1.0 driver revision:
0: uart:16550A port:000003F8 irq:4 tx:0 rx:0
...
4: uart:ST16650 port:00003000 irq:18 tx:0 rx:0
5: uart:ST16650 port:00003008 irq:18 tx:0 rx:0
6: uart:ST16650 port:00003010 irq:18 tx:0 rx:0
7: uart:ST16650 port:00003018 irq:18 tx:0 rx:0
8: uart:ST16650 port:00003020 irq:18 tx:0 rx:0
9: uart:ST16650 port:00003028 irq:18 tx:0 rx:0
10: uart:ST16650 port:00003030 irq:18 tx:0 rx:0
11: uart:ST16650 port:00003038 irq:18 tx:0 rx:0
12: uart:unknown port:00000000 irq:0
...
31: uart:unknown port:00000000 irq:0`
```

I can

```
struct pci_access *pciAccess;
struct pci_dev *dev;
pciAccess = pci_alloc(); 
pci_init(pciAccess);                                 
pci_scan_bus(pciAccess);                             
for (dev = pciAccess->devices; dev; dev = dev->next) 
{
    pci_fill_info(dev, PCI_FILL_IDENT); 
    if (dev->vendor_id == VENDOR_ID_UUT)
    {
        printf("%04x:%02x:%02x.%d vendor=%04x device=%04x  base0=%lx\n",
            dev->domain, dev->bus, dev->dev, dev->func, dev->vendor_id, dev->device_id,
            (long)dev->base_addr[0]&0xFFF0);
    }
}
pci_cleanup(pciAccess);
```

but it still doesn't give me a way to *programmatically* select the 8 ttyS devices associated with the card(s) detected.

Do I really need to shell `setserial` and parse the output??

Comment: I’ve written and maintained a PCI (et al) kernel driver loadable module for Linux for years, and similar for Windows for *decades*, but haven’t found a technique for this without spawning some terminal commands and string parsing…

Comment: Have you inspected the directory **/proc/tty/driver/** where there should a file per each type of **tty** (e.g. **serial** and **usbserial**), and each file should list an instance of a port?  Note that accessing that directory requires superuser privileges.

Comment: excerpt from /proc/tty/driver:
`:/proc/tty/driver# cat serial
4: uart:ST16650 port:3000 irq:18 tx:0 rx:0
5: uart:ST16650 port:3008 irq:18 tx:0 rx:0
6: uart:ST16650 port:3010 irq:18 tx:0 rx:0
7: uart:ST16650 port:3018 irq:18 tx:0 rx:0
8: uart:ST16650 port:3020 irq:18 tx:0 rx:0
9: uart:ST16650 port:3028 irq:18 tx:0 rx:0
10: uart:ST16650 port:3030 irq:18 tx:0 rx:0
11: uart:ST16650 port:3038 irq:18 tx:0 rx:0`
however, there's no indication how to relate this info to which PCI device the ports were installed by